# How to supply multiple options with array validation?

Tags: python, python-click

Given I have code like this:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

@click.option('--columns', is_flag=False, 
  default=columns, show_default=True, metavar='<columns>', type=click.Choice(columns), 
  help='Sets target columns', multiple=True)
```

Then I can call my app like this:

```
./myapp --columns=col1
```

**However**, how to make this work with multiple items separated by comma, like so:

```
./myapp --columns=col1,col3
```

My goal is to retrieve the passed values from an resulting `columns` array `['col1', 'col3']`.

I do NOT want to pass the option multiple times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `multiple` keyword in `click.option` is so you can pass the same option multiple times, e.g. `--columns=col1 --columns=col2`. Instead you can accept a string for columns and then extract and validate the columns yourself:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

@click.option('--columns', is_flag=False, default=','.join(cols), show_default=True,
              metavar='<columns>', type=click.STRING, help='Sets target columns')
@click.command()
def main(columns):
    # split columns by ',' and remove whitespace
    columns = [c.strip() for c in columns.split(',')]

    # validate passed columns
    for c in columns:
        if c not in cols:
            raise click.BadOptionUsage("%s is not an available column." % c)

    print(columns)
```

Comment: That is a wonderful answer and great python code. (I never saw the `[c.strip()... ` part, wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: Seems strange that this isn't provided as part of the default `click` package.

Answer (score 4):

There's an option in click to perform [argument validation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#callbacks-for-validation)

> If you want to apply custom validation logic, you can do this in the
>   parameter callbacks. These callbacks can both modify values as well as
>   raise errors if the validation does not work

Here's how your code might look like with it in use:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']  


def _arg_split(ctx, param, value):                                              
    # split columns by ',' and remove whitespace                                
    columns = [c.strip() for c in value.split(',')]                             

    # validate passed columns                                                   
    for c in columns:                                                           
        if c not in cols:                                                       
            raise click.BadOptionUsage("%s is not an available column." % c)    

    return columns                                                              


@click.option('--columns', is_flag=False, default=','.join(cols),               
              show_default=True, metavar='<columns>',                           
              required=True, type=click.STRING, help='Sets target columns',     
              callback=_arg_split)                                              
@click.command()                                                                
def main(columns):                                                              
    print(columns)
```

Note that the **columns** variable fed into the **main** is already a list so that you can use right away without any processing